# Reference to generic type 'Map' requires arguments in <...> - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, realm, objectmapper

After updating the Xcode to 12.5 and updating all the pods , i start getting the above error in all files where mapping is happening

> Reference to generic type 'Map' requires arguments in <...>
> Insert '<<#Key: _MapKey#>, <#Value: RealmCollectionValue#>>'

```
class DayPartData: Object, Mappable {
    @objc dynamic var code = 0
    @objc dynamic var text : String?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        code <- map["code"]
        text <- map["text"]
    }
}
```

am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not using this pod but the error message is pretty straightforward it seems. Did you check the documentation and/or the release notes for the new version?

Comment: Since you're been using Map previously, and a [Map<>](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/data-types/map/) type was just added to Realm (currently as beta) is your question about the Map object from a third party library or the `Map<>` object Realm just introduced? I assume it's about the third party [Map](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper) library. You may want to consider removing that and rolling you code over the the Realm Map

Answer (score 9):

Realm has added new collection type 'Map<String, T> ', It's like a Dictionary. coincidentally, Map is a class belongs to ObjectMapper. So, You just need to add ‘ObjectMapper’ before the ‘ Map’ to distinguish it. like this

```
class DayPartData: Object, Mappable {
@objc dynamic var code = 0
@objc dynamic var text : String?
required convenience init?(map: ObjectMapper.Map) {
    self.init()
}
func mapping(map: ObjectMapper.Map) {
    code <- map["code"]
    text <- map["text"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use realm version 10.7.6 instead of new. Because after they added new Map<> type.
I had the same error 2 hours ago.)